# Convert minutes to days, hours and minutes using moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment js to convert minutes in to days, hours and minutes

```
moment.utc().startOf('year').add({ minutes: timeInMinute }).format('D [Days and ]HH[ Hours and ]mm');
```

(timeInMinute is my input variable)
this is work fine for hours and minutes, but when the input value is 1441 it gives,

**2 Days and 00 Hours and 01 Minutes.**

it should really be **1 Days and 00 Hours and 01 minutes**.

What am I doing wrong? please help me

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use Momentjs and not plain Javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `moment.duration` to calculate hours, days, minutes etc from a time duration:

```
var duration = moment.duration(1422, 'minutes');
```

Then you can do:

```
duration.days();
```

or

```
duration.hours();
```

Here is the [official documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)

**Note:** Please read the project status at the top of the above official link.