# Using Moment library, what is the correct syntax to convert minutes into days hours and minutes that also formats for singular vs plural?

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs, angular-moment

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've been struggling to find a solution for this question:

1. Using `Moment` library, what is the correct syntax to convert minutes into days hours and minutes that also formats for singular vs plural?

expected: `2009 minutes` would become: `1 day 9 hours 29 minutes`

here is the incorrect code:

```
function durationFormatter(minutes): string {
  const ms = minutes * 60000;
  const days = Math.floor(ms / 8.64e7);
  const msOnLastDay = ms - days * 8.64e7;

  return moment.utc(msOnLastDay)
    .format("D [days] H [hours] M [minutes]");
}

console.log('durationFormatter -->', durationFormatter(2009));
```

The above outputs:

`1 days 9 hours 1 minutes` which is wrong

I also tried this other moment package `moment-duration-format` with this syntax: (per docs = https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#basics)

```
import momentDurationFormatSetup from 'moment-duration-format';

function durationFormatter(minutes): string {
  momentDurationFormatSetup();
  return moment.duration(minutes, "minutes").format();
}
```

But I get this error:
Property 'format' does not exist on type 'Duration'

How would I use this with the package?

Comment: You really ought to be looking at *durations* instead of milliseconds since 1970: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/. The `humanize` method may already be close enough to your goal.

Comment: I was using durations first but it wouldn't work with format not being recognized - just updated the question

Comment: Durations don’t have a `format` method. Read the documentation. Again, `humanize` may be close enough.

Comment: I'll take a look but the documentation I was looking at had it => https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#basics

Comment: For the moment-duration-format package, you seem to be missing the important step of setting up that extension correctly.

Comment: So looking at the humanize = 
moment.duration(1, "minutes").humanize(); // a minute 

.....I would need it to output --> "1 minute" not "a minute"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert minutes to days, hours and minutes using moment js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63772083/convert-minutes-to-days-hours-and-minutes-using-moment-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the excellent library [humanizeDuration](https://github.com/EvanHahn/HumanizeDuration.js), simply passing:

`humanizeDuration(2009 * 60 * 1000, { delimiter: ' '})`

will output what you wanted - 1 day 9 hours 29 minute.

Note - you pass milliseconds, so you need to multiple the minutes parameter by 60,000 before passing to humanizeDuration

Comment: Checking it out now! Thanks for your input.

Comment: It worked beautifully! Really straight forward. Thank you.